# PHP - function reflection - get all return values without running the function

Tags: php, function, reflection, return-value

I have a function like

```
function foo($p){
   if ($p == "") return 0;
   return 5;
}
```

Is it possible somehow to get all return values that function can return (in this case 0 and 5)? I can run the function, but I dont know which value will case which return.

I am building some kind of a plugin system and this function is user defined as a lambda. So I dont know its complexity or possible inputs. To be able to get all return values, it would increase user-friendliness. Currently, user have to specify it manually via variable in function like this:

```
function setLambda($lambda, array $returnValues)...
```

**EDIT:**

The return value will always be integer number. To make things easier, I expect the return value to be hard-coded like in the example, not calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a function like

```
function test($input)
{
 return $input;
}
```

The output could be every possible string, array, integer, float, object, ... I think you get what I mean.
I don't think you will be able to forecast all possible returned values, so the answer is **no**.

Comment: Even if the return value is hard-coded number like in the example?

Comment: PHP doesn't know if you have a hard coded or variable return value

Comment: I know, but maybe convert function to a string somehow and use regexp to get return values?

Comment: What if you just declare it? You know what you coded so just pass it into a variable?

Comment: Thats sort of my current solution :-)